# Perform image transformations on batches of images in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

I am trying to perform some transformations on a batch of images of size [128,128,3] with a batch_size of 20. I have managed to do part of the transformations on a single image but I'm not sure how to extend the same for the entire batch.

`x` is the batched image tensor of shape [20,128,128,3]

`grads` is also a tensor of shape [20,128,128,3]

I want to find the maximum value of `grads` per image ie I will get 20 max values. Let us call the max value for image_i as max_grads_i.

`add_max_grads` is a tensor of shape [20,128,128,3]

I want to update the value of `add_max_grads` such that for image_i I need to update the corresponding `add_max_grads` at the position of the max_grads_i in `grads` tensor and I need to update this across the 3 channels.

For instance, for image i the shape is [128,128,3], if the `max_grads_i` was found at `grads[50][60][1]`, I want to update `add_max_grads` at [50][60][0], [50][60][1], [50][60][2] with the same constant value.

Eventually, this needs to be extended for all the images in the batch to create `add_max_grads` which has a shape [20,128,128,3].

How can I achieve this?

Currently I am using `tf.math.reduce_max(grads,(1,2,3))` to find the max value in the `grads` tensor for each image in the batch which returns a tensor of shape [20,] but I'm stuck at the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you're asking, if I've understood it right.

This is a self-contained example.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
#tshape = (20,128,128,3)     # The real shape needed
tshape = (2,4,4,3)           # A small shape, to allow print output to be readable

# A sample x vector, set to zeros here so we can see what gets updated easily
x = tf.zeros(shape=tshape, dtype=tf.float32)

# grads, same shape as x, let's use a random matrix here
grads = tf.random.normal(shape=tshape)
print(f"grads: \n{grads}")

# ---- Now calculate the indices we will use in tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update
# 4-D mask tensor (m, x, y, c) with 1 in max locations (by m), zeros otherwise
mask4d = tf.cast(grads == tf.reduce_max(grads, axis=(1,2,3), keepdims=True), dtype=tf.int32)
# 3D mask tensor (m, x, y) with 1 in max pixel locations (by m) across channel
mask3d = tf.reduce_max(mask4d, axis=3)
# indices of maximum values, each item gives m, x, y
indices = tf.where(mask3d)
print(f"\nindices\n{indices}")

# ---- Now calculate the updates we will use in tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update. This has shape (m, c)
newval = 999
updates = tf.constant(newval, shape=(tshape[0], tshape[3]), dtype=tf.float32)

# ---- Now modify x by scattering newval through it. Each entry in indices indicates a slice x[m, x, y, :]
x_updated = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(x, indices, updates)
print(f"\nx_updated\n{x_updated}")
```

Comment: Yep that's exactly what I was looking for, thankyou! `tensor_scatter_nd_update` was super useful to learn.